# With Metal (vs OpenGL), How does color/alpha blending work on single-channel render targets?

Tags: opengl, metal, alphablending, blending

I'm porting some OpenGL code from a technical paper to use with Metal.  In it, they use a render target with only one channel - a 16-bit float buffer. But then they set blending operations on it like this:

```
glBlendFunci(1, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

With only one channel, does that mean that with OpenGL, the target defaults to being an alpha channel?

Does anyone know if it is the same with Metal?  I am not seeing the results I expect and I am wondering if Metal differs, or if there is a setting that controls how single-channel targets are treated with regards to blending.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but having a single channel framebuffer doesn't mean that the shader can't output an alpha value in addition. You won't have a destination alpha stored but there can still be a source alpha which can be used in the blending calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenGL, [image format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format) channels are labeled explicitly with their channels. There is only one one-channel color format: `GL_R*` (obviously with different bitdepths and other info). That is, red-only. And while [texture swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Swizzle) can make the red channel appear in other channels from a texture fetch, that doesn't work for framebuffer writes.

Furthermore, that blend function doesn't actually use the *destination* alpha. It only uses the source alpha, which has the value the FS gave it. So the fact that the framebuffer doesn't store an alpha is essentially irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks -- I am still a little confused though.  In this example, the destination  multiplier is 1 - srcAlpha.  What is srcAlpha in this case?  Normally I would think it is the alpha value returned by the fragment shader, is that not correct?  But there is no alpha value for a shader whose target is a single channel.  Do you see my confusion?

Comment: @bsabiston: "*But there is no alpha value for a shader whose target is a single channel.*" Says who? The source alpha is the *output* from the fragment shader. That output doesn't care what the framebuffer does or does not contain. Only the *destination* values care about that.

Comment: My fragment shader outputs a single float, since it targets a single-channel buffer.   And from what I can tell, Metal seems to think that is a color value, not an alpha value.

Comment: If the fragment shader output has fewer than 4 components, the missing components are assumed to be those from `<type>4(0, 0, 0, 1)`. So, the source alpha is 1. Given the blend func you're supposedly using (source factor 0, dest factor 1 - source alpha == 0), that would imply that only zeroes are written to the destination.

Comment: @KenThomases: Can you cite a location in the specification that specifies this? For example, 10.3.5 is what defines this to be true for vertex shader attributes. Where is the corresponding location for fragment shaders?

Comment: @KenThomases that lines up with what I am seeing - nothing! :) I think this is where Metal and OpenGL differ -- the OpenGL shader is able to return a regular float4 with the value it wants to be in the alpha buffer.  But I have to return a single value in Metal to match the bound buffer -- which means I think I need to use srcColor instead of srcAlpha in the blend functions.

Comment: Why do you believe you have to return a single float? Your fragment shader should be able to return a `float4`.

Comment: @NicolBolas, you appear to be referring to the OpenGL spec, I think. I'm talking about Metal. Unfortunately, I still can't point to definitive documentation. The Metal spec is decidedly non-comprehensive.

Comment: @KenThomases Ah I see you are right.  I was under the mistaken impression that I got errors if the return type didn't match the bound buffer, but I didn't realize I could specify a return type buffer in the shader that does not match the actual bound buffer, and not get errors.  Thanks!

Comment: A "return type buffer"? The shader return type (or the `[[color]]` field of a struct return type) must match the render target texture in general type (`float` vs. `int` vs. `uint`) but not necessarily in number of components.